# Method to edit britghtness and contrast of multiple photos (each conditioned differently)

Tags: photo-editing

We've been given a task to edit the brightness and contrast of around 1000 multiple different photos (each conditioned differently, different exposure, saturation, etc), so as to match the condition of the brightness setting of the monitor of our client (that is without changing it's monitor settings).

Previously this was done in Lightroom CS6, but it seems to be more suitable and faster to use Lightroom CS6 for editing a batch of photos that was taken more or less with the same settings of the camera and the same surrounding condition. Currently we are doing this in Photoshop CS6 by assigning a shorter shortcut key for the brightness and contrast dialog box (usually it is ALT+I+A+C which prove to be tedious doing so repetitively) then opening Mini Bridge as to switch from the current photo to the next photo that we want to edit without having to switch applications. This the method was much faster in doing such a task compared to the way that we used Lightroom CS6.

The one problem we had in Lightroom is that after we change the exposure and/or contrast of a photo in Lightroom, then opening it again, the exposure and contrast number does not go back to zero by default. This is different in Photoshop CS6, when you close the brightness and contrast dialog box and then open it again, the arrow points in the middle of the bar again.

I was wondering is there any other method to do the above task, that is much more faster? or using another application? I'm using Windows 10 btw. Regards,

Note: We only want to edit each of the photos brightness and contrast properties no other than that. After editing we do intentionally want to save the editings to the original photo so everytime the application ask us do we want to replace the original file, we always answer yes. And also the customer  browse the photos in a different picture browsing application (not lightroom). That's why we wanted to edit in the original photos.

Comment: What do you mean by "match the condition of the brightness setting of the monitor of our client"?

Comment: Since the monitor of our client is set to a much darker setting we had to increase the brightness of the photos. Since he has eyes issues you see..

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to increase or decrease all images equally, then go to the Quick Develop setting of the Library, change to Grid mode to select all the images (as many as you like) and use the exposure buttons.  These go up and down a RELATIVE amount, I think it's 1/3rd of a stop for the first button and 1 stop for the other.  These are also very handy if you want to slightly warm a lot of different photos of different white balance, as again they are relative not absolute.